# Dividing numbers from columns csv

Tags: awk

I have a `CSV` with several columns. I want to divide the data between two columns and get only one decimal. How can I control it with bash?

I use the following code now

```
awk  -F "," '{$3=$2/$1; print $1","$2","$3} file
```

How can I control de number of decimals in $3?

Comment: you should use like `expr 4 / 2 `

Comment: Do you want a awk or a bash solution?

Comment: Are your numbers integer or floating point? Please add answers to your question.

Comment: I prefer to use awk solution in order to take profit of the above command. I use integers. But if you show me a solution for float numbers I will apreciate it for future cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it all in Awk.

```
awk  -F "," '{printf "%s,%s,%4.2f\n", $1 , $2, $2/$1 }' file
```

[Link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html#Printf) for proper documentation.

Comment: Triplee, imagine I have more columns...awk  -F "," '{$7=$4-$5; $3=$2/$1; print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6","$7} file  where $7 are words... do I have to describe in all the fields if is integer, float...can I only do it with $3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or why you want to overwrite the columns you have.  You could do `$7 = sprintf("%4.2f", $4-$5)` to assign a numeric value to `$7` with the desired precision, but then there is no guarantee that Awk will keep that precision if the last digits are zero (though mine seems to keep it, as long as you are not doing additional calculations on the values, and just keeping them as strings).